# Get all items from an array that is imported via fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, electron

I need to be able to get the values from
`jsonParsed.students[actStudent].evnetsPartaken`
Which is an array and would be for example `[1,2,0]`
(example, not full data, check attachments for full data)

```json
{
    "students":
    [

    { 
        
        "firstName":"John", 
             "lastName":"Doe", 
             "gradeNum":"9",
             "serviceHours":99.00,
             "studentNotes":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sem magna, commodo nec enim quis.",
             "evnetsPartaken":[1,3.1] 
            },
    { 
        
        "firstName":"SamSame", 
             "lastName":"SamSame", 
             "serviceHours":234,
              "studentNotes":":trollface.jpg:",
             "evnetsPartaken":[1,3] 
            },
    {
```

Each value corelates to  the array number of the event event in the `configEvents` json array

Again this is not the full data set

```json
[
"configEvents":
  [

  { 
      
     
           "eventName":"Football", 
           "isSport": true,
           "eventTags":["exampleTag1","exampleTag2"],
           "evnetDates":[13934823420,12892839483,23642834823 ]
          },
  { 
      
       
           "eventName":"Softball", 
           "isSport": true,
           "eventTags":["exampleTag1","exampleTag2"],
           "evnetDates":[13934823420,12892839483,23642834823 ]
          },
          { 
      
           "eventName":"Spirt Rally", 
           "isSport": false,
           "eventTags":["inSchool","exampleTag2"],
           "evnetDates":[878687686868 ]
          },
  { 
      
           "eventName":"Grade Party", 
           "isSport": false,
           "eventTags":["inSchool","exampleTag2"],
           "evnetDates":[82832497686868 ]
          } 
]
```

I can't figure how how to get the array values  `jsonParsed.students[actStudent].evnetsPartaken[]`

```js
fs.readFile('./testdata.json', 'utf8', (error, data) => {
     if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
     }

     //Store the json data output
     var jsonData = data;
     //Store a JSON Parsed version of the data (object.based )
     var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(jsonData)
    //One liner made by Dinesh Soni to make it easier to extracted values from json objects, example and article can be found in readme



     console.log(jsonParsed);
     console.log(jsonParsed.students);
     var actStudent = 1;
     var actEvents = 
     console.log(jsonParsed.students[actStudent].firstName + " " + jsonParsed.students[actStudent].lastName + " Partakes in " + (
      jsonParsed.configEvents[
      jsonParsed.students[1].evnetsPartaken[] //issue is here (this is the said arguments)
    ].eventName
      ));

})
```

It works fine if I put the arguments myself but that's not a solution
Is there a proper way to get these values, it should be notted `actStudent` is just for testing and will be changing a lot in the real program

I need to get it inside of this

```js
jsonParsed.configEvents[jsonParsed.students[1].evnetsPartaken[]].eventName
```

for it to properly work
because .students[1].evnetsPartaken[] tells it what event arrays to use and then everything ouside of the brackets uses that data to get the correct event information
for example
jsonParsed.configEvents[jsonParsed.students[1].evnetsPartaken[0]].eventName

`would return Softball because it would corelate to configEvents[1].eventName which is Softball`

1. in my example

   ```
   "evnetsPartaken":[1,3]
   ```

   With a imput of [0] would get the first argument because you count from zero for jsons
2. After doing that you would get Event array [1] which is Softball

   [testdata.json on pastecord](https://pastecord.com/uvekadegyg)
   [main.js on pastecord](https://pastecord.com/umepapujob)

Indexing the files is not a solution and would only be a tempary fix. I tried doing a for loop but I got syntax erros when doing it. ps I am new to electron so I may be doing something really stupid. This is my first project and its... due tomarrow so I don't have much time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you iialexidai

> map gives me them as an array I selected only the eventName like your code is supposed to

```js
console.log(jsonParsed.students[actStudent].firstName + " " + jsonParsed.students[actStudent].lastName + " Partakes in " + (
    jsonParsed.students[actStudent].evnetsPartaken.map(evnet => jsonParsed.configEvents[evnet].eventName).join(`, `)
));
```